# Preselecting a NSComboBox Entry

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift3, nscombobox

I have a modal window that contains a NSComboBox. "Uses Data Source" is set to turn and the combobox correctly lists the entries. The view controller is the delegate for the data source. When I call the modal window to update an existing object I would like the combobox to display the selected entry if there is one. How do I do this?

I've tried to access the entries in viewWillAppear. I get and error saying there are no entries. The various print statements I have in the code indicate that the values aren't loaded until the drop down arrow is clicked. The two function I'm supplying as the delegate are:

```
func numberOfItems(in comboBox: NSComboBox) -> Int
func comboBox(_ comboBox: NSComboBox, objectValueForItemAt index: Int) -> Any?
```

Would it be possible to set the selected entry in the second function above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `NSComboBox` is a subclass of `NSTextField` you should be able to set its text by setting the `stringValue` property of your comboBox.

```
self.comboBox.stringValue = "Hello World"
```